# Allow user to refresh data connection to BigQuery on GoogleSheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I would like to setup our organisation's Bigquery IAM so that some users would have access to views under our "Report" dataset, which are queried on Google Sheets. Users with edit rights on these Google Sheets should be able to hit the refresh button and access latest data.

We achieved this by granting some user access to the entire project, but that's very poor security. Instead, I want to limit their access to either the entire "Report" dataset or to specific views under that dataset.

We tried to define some custom role and share the dataset but there is no "refresh" button on the sheet for the user to refresh.

Sharing the dataset with a viewer roles showed the Refresh button but they were not allowed to refresh:

[image]

What did we miss?

Comment: Have you tried to have a read only spreadsheet and utilized the import range function? Have you considered using an API with table data and sending some random text in the URL as if you were sending a GET with some fields? This would effectively force google sheets to update the information. While also limiting your clients access to your data. I think both would be viable options. If you don't have a web dev handily available, then I would go with the first option.

Answer (score -1):

For access to BigQuery data in Google Sheets, one should have:

- An Enterprise Plus, G Suite Enterprise for Education, Enterprise
  Standard, or Enterprise Essentials account.
- Access to BigQuery.
- A project with a billing setup in BigQuery.
- A BigQuery Job Creator role on the selected billing project.
- BigQuery Data Viewer role on the datasets containing the selected table.

According to this [document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9703001?hl=en&ref_topic=9699960):

> If you share a sheet with someone who doesn't meet the criteria above,
> they'll be able to see analysis created with Connected Sheets and
> perform regular Sheets operations, but they won't be able to refresh
> it or create their own connected sheet.

If you share a sheet with someone who doesn't have access to the correct data tables, they won't be able to create or refresh Connected Sheets analysis, and will need to contact the BigQuery admin.